# Facebook: where is location of photo in graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

Since we can now add location to individual photo in Facebook, does anyone know how to access that piece of information on the graph?

For example, at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
if I look at my News Feed graph, I see the recent photos I've uploaded with location.

But if I look at Photo Tags or the Photo API,
nothing is said about the location.

1.) Can someone explain to me why is that?

2.) How do I get all my geo-referenced photos then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct, Facebook is either hiding that information from API users, or has not gotten around to exposing it in the public version of their API.
2. We must wait for Facebook to expose this information to 3rd party developers.

Comment: A facebook engineer indicated that there may be a "place" field that accepts a place ID when adding an image, but I haven't got it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8756378/59913 
I've also tried permutations like 'place_id','uid','location','location_data', etc. Maybe a red herring, but looking at the network traffic when I set a location manually, it appears that a location is a special kind of tag in the image.

Comment: I don't know how long it has been since the API shows it, but the information is available now in the endpoint userid/photos as place.